# Previous domain owner receives emails 2 years after transfer

Tags: email, domain, mx-record

Two years ago I purchased a domain from a seller. The domain was hosted from his godaddy account then transferred to my godaddy account. A few days ago, the seller sends me an email saying that he has occasionally been receiving a few emails addressed to my domain name. He also includes a copy of an email as proof.

1. The seller was originally hosting the domain on godaddy with email forwarding settings on.
2. After I took ownership of the domain, I created a google apps account for the domain in question, and
3. I created an aws Route 53 zone with the MX records pointing to
   googlemail
4. I set the name servers of the domain on godaddy to point to the AWS
   nameservers.

The previous owner of the domain believes that the email forwarding settings on godaddy were not properly reset during the transfer.

After 3 phone calls of 20 minutes with godaddy, they are convinced the problem is not on their end.

I have reviewed all of the AWS route 53 settings and my google apps settings and there are no references to the previous owner's servers or email addresses.

All of my MX records points to googlemail.

I do not have any email plan or email forwarding plans on my godaddy account.

I do not know where else to look.

Comment: I would start by looking at the headers on one of these mystery emails.

Answer (score 1):

Was the email spam by any chance?

We used to see this a lot for spam - the spammer's (broken) mail systems would cache the DNS lookup forever, and keep sending to the same IP address no matter what.

Also follow the other user's suggestions - let's see the headers of this email.